# Sending messages from multiple servers to one Service Broker Queue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have a couple of SQL servers with databases supporting two different applications. I need to  capture changes to similar data from each database, but process it sequentially. Service Broker fits the bill, I just have a couple of implementation questions.

I've created a "third" database for extending the two applications. On this database, I've enabled service broker, created a message schema, contracts, service and queue.

If I want to send messages of this type `//mysite.com/extensions/message` to an `ExtensionsQueue` on `EXTENSIONSERVER.Database` from `LEGACYSERVER.Database`, do I need to run the SQL statements to create those pieces (schema, contract, message, etc) in each database I want to talk to this queue from? It seems that, minimum, I would need the message schema in each database to force integrity.

Assuming I need to (which only seems to make sense) should I name the services, queues, etc on each server the same, or will that cause issues? For example, should I name the service on the `EXTENSIONSERVER` something like `//extensionserver/extensions/message` and `//legacyserver/extensions/message`? Do I even need to create a service and queue on `LEGACYSERVER` or would a route like this take care of it?

```
CREATE ROUTE 
WITH 
  SERVICE_NAME = '//extensionserver/extensions/message',
  ADDRESS = 'extensionserver:1433'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be quite a setup. I ended up mostly following [this tutorial](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Service+Broker/2797/).

One key point that it didn't mention though was routes for external database instances need to be in the MSDB database.